# Simple Boolean function

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

I currently have a table which currently displays information about a patient and calculates their waiting time.

I have a Boolean value in the patient table;

```
Name      Type       Value 
Examined  Tinyint(1) 0
```

I want a simple tick box function in the table for each row which allows the user to select if the patient has been examined; If the box is ticked then that row will disappear from the table but NOT the database.

How do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "a&e") or die('Could not select database.');

$query = "SELECT PatientID, Forename, Surname, Gender, Illness, Priority, Arrival_time,NOW() as now,ABS(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), Arrival_time)) as Waiting_Time FROM Patient";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query"); 

/**
 * Convert number of seconds into hours, minutes and seconds
 * and return an array containing those values
 *
 * @param integer $seconds Number of seconds to parse
 * @return array
 */
function secondsToTime($seconds)
{
    // extract hours
    $hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));

    // extract minutes
    $divisor_for_minutes = $seconds % (60 * 60);
    $minutes = floor($divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    // extract the remaining seconds
    $divisor_for_seconds = $divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    $seconds = ceil($divisor_for_seconds);

    // return the final array
    $obj = array(
        "h" => (int) $hours,
        "m" => (int) $minutes,
        "s" => (int) $seconds,
    );
    return $obj;
}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>PatientID</th>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Illness</th>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>Waiting Time</th>
<th>Examined</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){

//Select the  expected and discharge time for this patient.
  $query2 = "SELECT Abs(TIMEDIFF(Expected_Time,'00:00:00')) as Expected,Abs(TIMEDIFF(Discharge_Time,'00:00:00')) as Discharge ".
                "FROM priority_time ".
                "WHERE Illness = '".$row->Illness."'".
                    " AND Priority = '".$row->Priority."'".
                ";";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die("Invalid statement: ".$query2);

    $row2 = $result2->fetch_object();
    $expected =  $row2->Expected;

    $discharge  = $row2->Discharge;

    if($expected > $discharge){
        echo "There is a problem with the database consistency, expectedTime must be less than dischargeTime!";
    }
    //Set the patient color.
    if($row->Waiting_Time <  $expected && $row->Waiting_Time <  $discharge){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    if($row->Waiting_Time >=  $expected && $row->Waiting_Time <  $discharge){
        echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFF00">';
    }
    if($row->Waiting_Time >  $expected && $row->Waiting_Time >  $discharge){
        echo '<tr bgcolor="#FF0000">';
    }

    //Print patient info
     echo 
      "<td>" . $row->PatientID . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Forename . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Surname . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Gender . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Illness . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Priority . "</td>
          <td>" . gmdate("H:i:s", $row->Waiting_Time)." </td>";

    //Close row
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you already tried? If you have no clue: Easiest would be to get in touch with a js library (mootools, jquery, ...), you need a function that will be called when it should disappear, then change to css to let the row disappear and send a request via ajax (POST/GET) to a php file which will update the db

Comment: Adding a boolean value to the table patient, that indicates if he has been examined by a doctor.  adding a button on the table for the user, that clicks to indicate that they receive the patient, that changes this boolean to true. It is not achievable via this method?

Comment: Where is the button? You have 8 x `th` but only 7 x `td` each row. You need to change your query as well

Comment: the button would be a tick box; something like this <input type="checkbox" name="examined" value="">

Comment: so if it is ticked then the patient has been examined and changes the Boolean to true

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use JOIN to add some fields from another table
To select the only rows where Examined  Tinyint(1) 0 is zero it is better to use WHERE

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "a&e") or die('Could not select database.');

$query = "SELECT PatientID, Forename, Surname, Gender, Illness, Priority, Arrival_time, NOW() as now, ABS(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), Arrival_time)) as Waiting_Time, Abs(TIMEDIFF(Expected_Time,'00:00:00')) as Expected,Abs(TIMEDIFF(Discharge_Time,'00:00:00')) as Discharge FROM Patient
JOIN priority_time USING (Illness, Priority)
WHERE Examined = 0";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query"); 

/**
 * Convert number of seconds into hours, minutes and seconds
 * and return an array containing those values
 *
 * @param integer $seconds Number of seconds to parse
 * @return array
 */
function secondsToTime($seconds)
{
    // extract hours
    $hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));

    // extract minutes
    $divisor_for_minutes = $seconds % (60 * 60);
    $minutes = floor($divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    // extract the remaining seconds
    $divisor_for_seconds = $divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    $seconds = ceil($divisor_for_seconds);

    // return the final array
    $obj = array(
        "h" => (int) $hours,
        "m" => (int) $minutes,
        "s" => (int) $seconds,
    );
    return $obj;
}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>PatientID</th>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Illness</th>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>Waiting Time</th>
<th>Examined</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){

    $expected =  $row->Expected;

    $discharge  = $row->Discharge;

    if($expected > $discharge){
        echo "There is a problem with the database consistency, expectedTime must be less than dischargeTime!";
    }
    //Set the patient color.
    if($row->Waiting_Time <  $expected && $row->Waiting_Time <  $discharge){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    if($row->Waiting_Time >=  $expected && $row->Waiting_Time <  $discharge){
        echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFF00">';
    }
    if($row->Waiting_Time >  $expected && $row->Waiting_Time >  $discharge){
        echo '<tr bgcolor="#FF0000">';
    }

    //Print patient info
     echo 
      "<td>" . $row->PatientID . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Forename . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Surname . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Gender . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Illness . "</td>
      <td>" . $row->Priority . "</td>
          <td>" . gmdate("H:i:s", $row->Waiting_Time)." </td>";

    //Close row
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</html>
```